# Can this dynamic SQL be replaced with the regular SQL to improve performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql, sql-server-2017

I am using the following dynamic query, but  see that the performance is slow. I am not a big fan of dynamic SQL, and am looking for, if possible, a good clean and fast SQL alternative for the following. Thanks a million ton in advance! Here are some details:

In the following code, the final table missingfields_*xxxx* lists out the rows where we have a missing rule field.
table_name has the column *rule* that holds the column name of the table *trans_modelname* (this table can be found in the dynamic part of the sql)

```
DECLARE @rule NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @PeriodNumber INT = 1

DECLARE @SelectList NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @WhereList NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @ModelName as NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'modelname'
--DECLARE @MaxPeriods INT = 8
DECLARE @MaxPeriods INT

SELECT  @MaxPeriods =  count (*)
FROM 
(
SELECT [rule]

FROM  table_name
WHERE ModelName = @ModelName) ab


DECLARE db_cursor3 CURSOR FOR  


SELECT * FROM 

(
SELECT [rule]

FROM  table_name
WHERE ModelName = @ModelName) cd


OPEN db_cursor3   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor3 INTO @rule

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   

    BEGIN
        SELECT @SelectList = COALESCE(@SelectList + ', ', '') + '' + @rule + ' AS [GLSegment_' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(@PeriodNumber AS VARCHAR), 3) + ']'
        SELECT @SelectList as 'Selectlist'
        IF @PeriodNumber < @MaxPeriods
            BEGIN 
                SELECT @WhereList = COALESCE(@WhereList, '') + '(isnull([GLSegment_' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(@PeriodNumber AS VARCHAR), 3) + '],'''') = '''' ) OR '
                SELECT @WhereList  as 'Wherelist where periodnumber < maxperiods'
            END
        ELSE IF @PeriodNumber =  @MaxPeriods
            BEGIN
                SELECT @WhereList = COALESCE(@WhereList, '') + '(isnull([GLSegment_' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(@PeriodNumber AS VARCHAR), 3) + '], '''') = '''' )'
                SELECT @WhereList as 'Wherelist where periodnumber = maxperiods'
            END
        SET @PeriodNumber = @PeriodNumber + 1
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor3 INTO @rule
END   

CLOSE db_cursor3   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor3
-- build dynamic query
SET @SQL =
'SELECT * into missingfields_' + @ModelName + ' from trans_' + @ModelName + '
WHERE id in

(
SELECT id from 
(
    SELECT  id,  ' + @SelectList + '
    FROM    trans_' + @ModelName + ')A
    WHERE   ' + @WhereList + '

);
SELECT * from missingfields_' + @ModelName


PRINT @SQL
print 'missingfields_' +  @ModelName
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Please rewrite this code for me" isn't really a question. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [start here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Comment: If you mean *"Can I replace this Cursor with a dataset approach?"* the likely answer is yes; cursors are almost always used incorrectly. But Eric raises some good points on why we can't really help you as it stands.

Comment: Why do you think the dynamic SQL is the reason this is slow?

Comment: (And you can confirm that by taking the output of the `print` command(s) and running that set of statements independently. I'm going to bet it's still slow when not executed from dynamic SQL.)